# Access VBA: Query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: vba, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to code a button to update a row based on the ID entered by the user. The ID is an autonumber field generated by the table. The users can create rows with another button but when they need to fix a mistake, I want them to be able to update the row with the correct info. However, my code is giving me the error in the title.

This is the "Update" button:

```
Private Sub Command133_Click()

    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime " _
    & "(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.Text116 & "','" & Me.Text118 & "','" & Me.Text126 & "','" & Me.Text121 & "','" & Me.Text123 & "','" & Me.Text128 & "') WHERE ID='" & Me.Text135 & "';"

    Call ClearControl(Me.Text116)
    Call ClearControl(Me.Text118)
    Call ClearControl(Me.Text126)
    Call ClearControl(Me.Text121)
    Call ClearControl(Me.Text123)
    Call ClearControl(Me.Text128)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to that `WHERE` statement you have on the end of your SQL statement.  Using the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` method is used to insert a single row of supplied values, so having a WHERE clause doesn't make sense.

If, instead, you are trying to insert values for one or more rows in an existing table then you want to write your SQL something like:

```
 "INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment)
 SELECT '" & Me.Text116 & "', '" ... [your other fields go here] ... "'
 FROM [src_table] As t
 WHERE t.ID = '" & Me.Text135 & "';"
```

**EDIT**
If you are looking to update values in existing row(s) instead of trying to add new rows with the new values then you'll need something like this, instead:

```
"UPDATE tbl_Downtime SET job = '" & Me.Text116 & "', suffix = '" & Me.Text118 & "', production_date = #" & Me.Text126 & "#, reason = '" & Me.Text121 & "', downtime_minutes = " & Me.Text123 & ", comment = '" & Me.Text128 & "' WHERE t.ID = '" & Me.Text135 & "';"
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this syntax - everything from the SELECT statement onwards is red.

Comment: I played around with it and tried this: `dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment) SELECT '" & Me.Text116 & "','" & Me.Text118 & "','" & Me.Text126 & "','" & Me.Text121 & "','" & Me.Text123 & "','" & Me.Text128 & "' FROM tbl_Downtime As t WHERE t.ID = '" & Me.Text135 & "';"` - all in ONE line (because I didn't want to have to deal with that extra underscore you need to use in VBA). But now I'm getting another error: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` Any tips?

Comment: That might be caused because you're passing in text box values, which are text/char datatypes. If the production_date field is a datetime and downtime_minutes is a number you'll have to use `CDate()` and `CINT()` functions to convert them, first.  You should double-check your other fields' data types to see if you need to do any other conversions.

Comment: I simplified it to tackle each conversion one at a time, but I'm still getting a data type error: `dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (production_date) SELECT '" & CDate(Me.Text126) & "' FROM tbl_Downtime As t WHERE t.ID = '" & Me.Text135 & "';"` I set my form control to "Short Date", but it's still not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Access needs dates surrounded by `#` instead of `'`, and the integers shouldn't have any enclosing character.  I should've mentioned that before.

Comment: `dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (production_date) SELECT #Me.Text126# FROM tbl_Downtime As t WHERE t.ID = Me.Text135 ;"` I'm getting an error: `Syntax error in date in query expression '#Me.Text126'.`

Comment: The textbox values still have to be concatenated with the string: `" INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (production_date) SELECT #" & Me.Text126 & "# FROM tbl_Downtime As t WHERE t.ID = " & Me.Text135 & ";"`

Comment: That fixed the syntax errors, but now when I hit the button the form gets submitted but nothing changes in the table....

Comment: What struck me as strange at first was that I was still using an `INSERT` instead of something like `UPDATE`....might that be a possibility?

Comment: If nothing changed in the table it would be because none of the rows in the table satisfied your `WHERE` clause. `INSERT` adds new rows, while `UPDATE` changes values in existing rows. An update would be written very differently. I've edited my response with an `UPDATE` statement. It still won't update anything unless the `WHERE` is satisfied.

Comment: It's giving me an error: `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.` - We're getting close!!